# More elegant way to make main effects plot from factor columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have statistical analysis app and am adding multi-factor ANOVA.

The following MRE does what I want. Given a couple of factors and a response variable, it makes a two-way interaction line plot and a main effects boxplot.

The problem is that the code feels gross, especially the main effects plot code. I feel like there should be a more elegant way to do that.

```
library(ggplot2)

data<-mtcars#could be anything

#Interaction plot
factor_col<-c(2,10)#user inputs
data_col<-4#user inputs

plot_data<-data[c(factor_col,data_col)]#reduced data set

factor_col2<-1:(ncol(plot_data)-1)#columns of factors in reduced data set
data_col2<-ncol(plot_data)#column of data in reduced data set
plot_data[factor_col2]<-lapply(plot_data[factor_col2],factor)#make factors

x_name<-sym(names(plot_data)[1])#factor on x-axis
lines_name<-sym(names(plot_data)[2])#factor that will be different lines
data_name<-sym(names(plot_data)[3])#name of the data column

ggplot(data=plot_data,aes(x=!!x_name,y=!!data_name,color=!!lines_name,group=!!lines_name,linetype=!!lines_name,shape=!!lines_name))+
  stat_summary(fun = mean,geom="line")+
  stat_summary(fun = mean,geom="point")



#main effects
plot_data2<-rbind(plot_data,plot_data)#doubling the data for facet
name_A<-names(plot_data)[1]#Name of factor for facet
name_B<-names(plot_data)[2]#Name of factor for facet
rows<-nrow(plot_data)
plot_data2$facet<-c(rep(name_A,rows),rep(name_B,rows))#Add single column of facet names

plot_data2$level[plot_data2$facet==name_A]<-paste0(names(data)[factor_col[1]]," = ",data[,factor_col[1]])#level names for first factor
plot_data2$level[plot_data2$facet==name_B]<-paste0(names(data)[factor_col[2]]," = ",data[,factor_col[2]])#level names for second factor
plot_data2$level<-factor(plot_data2$level)#make levels a factor

ggplot(data = plot_data2,aes(y=!!data_name))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=level))+
  stat_summary(aes(x=level),fun="mean",geom="point")+
  facet_wrap(vars(facet),scales="free")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shorter way for the main effects plot, I'm sure could be improved, especially the selection of the y variable based on position.

```
library(tidyverse)
data_col_name <- names(select(mtcars, {{data_col}}))
mtcars %>%
  pivot_longer(factor_col) %>%
  mutate(level = paste(name, "=", value)) %>%
ggplot(aes(y=!!sym(data_col_name))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=level))+
  stat_summary(aes(x=level),fun="mean",geom="point")+
  facet_wrap(vars(name),scales="free")
```

[image]

And here's a similar thing for the first part, but I presume there is a tidier syntax for the "select-by-position" parts.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = !!sym(names(select(mtcars, factor_col[1]))),
                   y = !!sym(names(select(mtcars, data_col))),
                   color = factor(!!sym(names(select(mtcars, factor_col[2])))),
                   linetype = factor(!!sym(names(select(mtcars, factor_col[2])))))) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean,geom="line")+
  stat_summary(fun = mean,geom="point")
```